# How to hide menu buttons in Android Studio Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I am using a tiling wm and the menu buttons which appear at the right side of the android emulator window are getting in my way. How do I remove them?

[image]

Comment: Probably you can't hide emulator toolbar